# Speed up row-wise point in polygon with Geopandas

Tags: python, point-in-polygon, geopandas

I have a geopandas `GeoDataframe` which contains some attributes and a `geometry` column which is filled with shapely `Point(lon, lat)` objects. Moreover, there is a `GeoSeries` which is equally indexed as the `GeoDataframe` and which contains shapely `Polygon()` objects. The polygons are derived from the [commonly known world borders shapefile](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) which means that many of them are rather large and complicated.

My goal is to join both GeoDataframes on a common attribute and then do a `point in polygon` test for each feature-pair, giving back all rows from the Points GeoDataframe for which the result is true. I think my approach given below works, however, it is quite slow and I wonder if there is any way to speed this up significantly.

In order to test this under similar conditions, you could download the `World Country Points` shapefile [from the bottom of this page](https://hiu.state.gov/data/data.aspx) to get approx. 180.000 points as well as [World Borders shapefile](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) to get the polygons. Save them in the same folder as your Python script, then load them into `GeoDataFrames` with

```
import geopandas as gpd

print('Reading points...')
PointsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('Global_Points_2013March12_HIU_USDoS.shp')
print('Reading polygons...')    
PolygonsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')
```

At first, I merge both dataframes into one while joining on the columns storing the two digit [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2), keeping keys from the Points GeoDataframe.

```
print('Merging GeoDataframes...')
merged = PointsGeodataframe.merge(PolygonsGeodataframe, left_on='iso_alpha2', right_on='ISO2', how='left')
print(merged.head(5))
```

Out:

```
CC   NAME_x REGION_x                                    geometry_x  \
0  AG  ALGERIA   AFRICA  POINT (-2.056197991715294 35.07505011900781)   
1  AG  ALGERIA   AFRICA   POINT (-1.93859720224998 35.08791119378083)   
2  AG  ALGERIA   AFRICA  POINT (-2.116729200249893 35.09038023113033)   
3  AG  ALGERIA   AFRICA  POINT (-2.136513829499904 35.09662084358041)   
4  AG  ALGERIA   AFRICA  POINT (-2.169619420782624 35.10288084768303)   

  iso_alpha2 iso_alpha3  iso_num  tld    AREA FIPS ISO2 ISO3     LAT    LON  \
0         DZ        DZA       12  .dz  238174   AG   DZ  DZA  28.163  2.632   
1         DZ        DZA       12  .dz  238174   AG   DZ  DZA  28.163  2.632   
2         DZ        DZA       12  .dz  238174   AG   DZ  DZA  28.163  2.632   
3         DZ        DZA       12  .dz  238174   AG   DZ  DZA  28.163  2.632   
4         DZ        DZA       12  .dz  238174   AG   DZ  DZA  28.163  2.632   

    NAME_y   POP2005  REGION_y  SUBREGION  UN  \
0  Algeria  32854159         2         15  12   
1  Algeria  32854159         2         15  12   
2  Algeria  32854159         2         15  12   
3  Algeria  32854159         2         15  12   
4  Algeria  32854159         2         15  12   

                                          geometry_y  
0  POLYGON ((2.96361 36.802216, 2.981389 36.80693...  
1  POLYGON ((2.96361 36.802216, 2.981389 36.80693...  
2  POLYGON ((2.96361 36.802216, 2.981389 36.80693...  
3  POLYGON ((2.96361 36.802216, 2.981389 36.80693...  
4  POLYGON ((2.96361 36.802216, 2.981389 36.80693...
```

To do a row-wise check if the Point (stored in `geometry_x`) is located within the polygon (stored in `geometry_y`) and get back all rows where this is the case, boolean indexing can be used (the `geometry_x` and `geometry_y` columns must be transformed into `GeoSeries` in order to use shapely's `within` on them:

```
rowsWherePointIsInPolygon = merged[gpd.GeoSeries(merged['geometry_x']).within(gpd.GeoSeries(merged['geometry_y']))]
print(rowsWherePointIsInPolygon)
```

This works fine for a small amount of rows. However, when doing this for the example shapefiles, it gets stuck for about half an hour on a rather fast machine and even longer on slow ones.

Is there any possibility to speed up this operation or is it already as fast as it gets? I don't think that there is any sense here to use a spatial index because the problem is not to find out to which of 400.000 polygons one point belongs to but to check if one point is in one polygon for a lot of points.

Without really knowing if this has something to do with it, I also tried setting

```
from shapely import speedups
speedups.enable()
```

but this did not make any change.

Comment: Could you use gpd.sjoin to begin with then do some difference analysis from there?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either using the geopandas-cython branch [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/tree/geopandas-cython) or [pygeos](https://github.com/caspervdw/pygeos).

If you use `pygeos`, I would recommend converting the geometries from shapely to the `pygeos` version first for the best speedups.