# Converting Pandas DataFrame to GeoDataFrame

Tags: csv, geopandas, pandas, geodataframe

This seems like a simple enough question, but I can't figure out how to convert a Pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame for a spatial join?

Here is an example of what my data looks like using `df.head()`:

```
    Date/Time           Lat       Lon       ID
0   4/1/2014 0:11:00    40.7690   -73.9549  140
1   4/1/2014 0:17:00    40.7267   -74.0345  NaN
```

In fact, this dataframe was created from a CSV so if it's easier to read the CSV in directly as a GeoDataFrame that's fine too.

Comment: use [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Convert the DataFrame's content (e.g. `Lat` and `Lon` columns) into appropriate [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) geometries first and then use them together with the original DataFrame to create a GeoDataFrame.

```py
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Lon, df.Lat)]
df = df.drop(['Lon', 'Lat'], axis=1)
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=geometry)
```

Result:

```
    Date/Time           ID      geometry
0   4/1/2014 0:11:00    140     POINT (-73.95489999999999 40.769)
1   4/1/2014 0:17:00    NaN     POINT (-74.03449999999999 40.7267)
```

---

Since the geometries often come in the WKT format, I thought I'd include an example for that case as well:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.wkt

geometry = df['wktcolumn'].map(shapely.wkt.loads)
df = df.drop('wktcolumn', axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=geometry)
```

Comment: Thanks again! That's much simpler and runs very fast - much better than iterating through every row of the df at my n=500,000 :)

Comment: Gosh, thanks! I check this answer like every 2 days :)

Comment: you'd think this would be the first entry in the documentation!

Comment: +1 for the shapely.wkt. It took me a while to figure this out!

Comment: In order to avoid deleting lat/lon columns from the pandas `df` (in case you need to use it later), I would instead recommend dropping lat/lon in the creation of `gdf` like so
`gdf = GeoDataFrame(df.drop(['Lon', 'Lat'], axis=1), crs=crs, geometry=geometry)`

Answer (score 56):

Update 201912: The official documentation at https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html does it succinctly using [`geopandas.points_from_xy`](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/4f7036acb8ff7d99b42a2440371272d6243e618e/geopandas/array.py#L200) like so:

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(x=df.Longitude, y=df.Latitude)
)
```

You can also set a `crs` or `z` (e.g. elevation) value if you want.

---

Old Method: Using shapely

One-liners! Plus some performance pointers for big-data people.

Given a `pandas.DataFrame` that has x Longitude and y Latitude like so:

```
df.head()
x   y
0   229.617902  -73.133816
1   229.611157  -73.141299
2   229.609825  -73.142795
3   229.607159  -73.145782
4   229.605825  -73.147274
```

Let's convert the `pandas.DataFrame` into a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` as follows:

Library imports and [shapely speedups](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#performance):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
shapely.speedups.enable() # enabled by default from version 1.6.0
```

Code + benchmark times on a test dataset I have lying around:

```
#Martin's original version:
#%timeit 1.87 s ± 7.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.drop(['x', 'y'], axis=1),
                                crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
                                geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.x, df.y)])



#Pandas apply method
#%timeit 8.59 s ± 60.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.drop(['x', 'y'], axis=1),
                       crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
                       geometry=df.apply(lambda row: shapely.geometry.Point((row.x, row.y)), axis=1))
```

Using `pandas.apply` is surprisingly slower, but may be a better fit for some other workflows (e.g. on bigger datasets using dask library):

Credits to:

- [Making shapefile from Pandas dataframe?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147156/making-shapefile-from-pandas-dataframe/182234#182234) (for the pandas apply method)
- [Speed up row-wise point in polygon with Geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140613/speed-up-row-wise-point-in-polygon-with-geopandas) (for the speedup hint)

Some Work-In-Progress references (as of 2017) for handling big `dask` datasets:

- http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/09/21/accelerating-geopandas-1
- https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/461
- https://github.com/mrocklin/dask-geopandas

Comment: Thanks for the comparison, indeed the zip version is way faster

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function taken from the internals of geopandas and slightly modified to handle a dataframe with a geometry/polygon column already in wkt format.

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import shapely

def df_to_geodf(df, geom_col="geom", crs=None, wkt=True):
  """
  Transforms a pandas DataFrame into a GeoDataFrame.
  The column 'geom_col' must be a geometry column in WKB representation.
  To be used to convert df based on pd.read_sql to gdf.
  Parameters
  ----------
  df : DataFrame
      pandas DataFrame with geometry column in WKB representation.
  geom_col : string, default 'geom'
      column name to convert to shapely geometries
  crs : pyproj.CRS, optional
      CRS to use for the returned GeoDataFrame. The value can be anything accepted
      by :meth:`pyproj.CRS.from_user_input() <pyproj.crs.CRS.from_user_input>`,
      such as an authority string (eg "EPSG:4326") or a WKT string.
      If not set, tries to determine CRS from the SRID associated with the
      first geometry in the database, and assigns that to all geometries.
  Returns
  -------
  GeoDataFrame
  """

  if geom_col not in df:
    raise ValueError("Query missing geometry column '{}'".format(geom_col))

  geoms = df[geom_col].dropna()

  if not geoms.empty:
    if wkt == True:
      load_geom = shapely.wkt.loads
    else:
      load_geom_bytes = shapely.wkb.loads
      """Load from Python 3 binary."""

      def load_geom_buffer(x):
        """Load from Python 2 binary."""
        return shapely.wkb.loads(str(x))

      def load_geom_text(x):
        """Load from binary encoded as text."""
        return shapely.wkb.loads(str(x), hex=True)

      if isinstance(geoms.iat[0], bytes):
        load_geom = load_geom_bytes
      else:
        load_geom = load_geom_text

    df[geom_col] = geoms = geoms.apply(load_geom)
    if crs is None:
      srid = shapely.geos.lgeos.GEOSGetSRID(geoms.iat[0]._geom)
      # if no defined SRID in geodatabase, returns SRID of 0
      if srid != 0:
        crs = "epsg:{}".format(srid)

  return GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geom_col)
```