# Convert polygon bounding box to geodataframe?

Tags: extents, shapely, geopandas, geodataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that contains bounding box information for tiled raster data in the following format.

```
left            bottom              right           top
466583.40921    3135701.9763599997  466586.39673    3135704.9638799997
466583.40921    3135698.98884       466586.39673    3135701.9763599997
466583.40921    3135696.0013200007  466586.39673    3135698.98884
466583.40921    3135693.013800001   466586.39673    3135696.0013200007
```

Ultimately, I am looking to create a geopandas geodataframe that has a `geometry` column with the bounding box information in the following format:

```
geometry
POLYGON ((466586.39673 3135701.97636, 466586.39673 3135704.96388, 466583.40921 3135704.96388, 466583.40921 3135701.97636, 466586.39673 3135701.97636))
POLYGON ((466586.39673 3135698.98884, 466586.39673 3135701.97636, 466583.40921 3135701.97636, 466583.40921 3135698.98884, 466586.39673 3135698.98884))
...and so on...
```

I am aware that I can create a `POLYGON` object using the box method and referencing a single row:

```
box(df.left[1], df.bottom[1], df.right[1], df.top[1])
```

I have also tried hacking together a solution from a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/174168/8104):

```
b = [x for x in box(df.left, df.bottom, df.right, df.top)]
```

Which yields the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I convert shapely bounding data as in the first dataframe to a geopandas geodataframe as in the second dataframe above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there with what you tried, and using the `box` method is indeed the best way. 
With the list comprehension, you can do

```
b = [box(l, b, r, t) for l, b, r, t in zip(df.left, df.bottom, df.right, df.top)]
```

Another option is to apply the box function to each row of your dataframe:

```
b = df.apply(lambda row: box(row.left, row.bottom, row.right, row.top), axis=1)
```

Once you have converted the bounding boxes to polygons, make sure to actually create a GeoDataFrame:

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=b)
```

Answer (score 8):

A full solution including imports:

```
from shapely.geometry import box
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd

INIT_PATH = './data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(INIT_PATH, sep='\t')
geometry = [box(x1, y1, x2, y2) for x1,y1,x2,y2 in zip(df.left, df.bottom, df.right, df.top)]
df = df.drop(['left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top'], axis=1)
geodf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)

print(geodf.head())
```

Gives:

```
    geometry
0  POLYGON ((466586.397 3135701.976, 466586.397 3...
1  POLYGON ((466586.397 3135698.989, 466586.397 3...
2  POLYGON ((466586.397 3135696.001, 466586.397 3...
3  POLYGON ((466586.397 3135693.014, 466586.397 3...
```