# af.to_file("output.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas

```
af = pd.merge(df, gdf, left_on='DA Code', right_on='DAUID', how='left')
af.to_file("output.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")
```

I am trying to export my geopandas dataframe adfter a merge.  the orginal gdf is experting fine but the new one is giving me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-85d4fd06b055> in <module>
----> 1 af.to_file("output.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'
```

The merged gdf looks fine. Do I have to declare the geometry column manually?
[image]

Comment: That's because `af` is not a gpd.GeoDataFrame it's a pd.DataFrame.  Use geopandas merging, not pandas https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html

Comment: You should convert your df to gdf.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174159/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-geodataframe